# NASM align attribute default value

Tags: assembly, nasm

I have read in NASM manual that align attribute specify how many low bits of the segment start address must be forced to zero.

quote

> ALIGN is used, as shown above, to specify how many low bits of the
>   segment start address must be forced to zero. The alignment value
>   given may be any power of two from 1 to 4096; in reality, the only
>   values supported are 1, 2, 4, 16, 256 and 4096, so if 8 is specified
>   it will be rounded up to 16, and 32, 64 and 128 will all be rounded up
>   to 256, and so on. Note that alignment to 4096-byte boundaries is a
>   PharLap extension to the format and may not be supported by all
>   linkers.

[LINK](http://cs.nyu.edu/courses/fall02/V22.0201-001/nasm_doc_html/nasmdoc6.html)

If is not specified any align attribute, is considered as 0 or 1?

Comment: Since alignment is essentially a denominator, 0 doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the other formats where align is supported, the linked documentation page lists the defaults. For the `bin` format it doesn't, but a quick check (that you could have easily performed too) shows it's `4`.

Comment: Sorry ... you are right, I have read the align section but was mention above. Thanks (BTW is not 4)

Answer (score 0):

My selfmade alignment using the "org" directive:

```
START:

org START + ((($-START)/8)*8)+8

org START + ((($-START)/32)*32)+32

org START + ((($-START)/128)*128)+128
```